# Unity and Vuforia: How to change FOV

Tags: vuforia

I have an issue with the AR Camera. I need to change the field of view but I can't find where I can do it.
I'm using Unity 5.5 and Vuforia 6.1.17

Do you have any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For consistency with your Vuforia app and other features of your phone, Vuforia, forces the field of view to be the same as your phone's camera. I believe that even if you change the value manually by zooming the camera in and out, that value will just be replaced by the original field of view.

I believe this is done because changing the field of view will cause warping of your 3d models and such that are parented to the Image targets.

You may be able to work around this, though, by directly modifying the VuforiaBehaviour.cs script but I have no clue how.

Comment: Thank you, I supposed it is not possible because of the issues it will bring with the virtual world.